# Ошибка при установке php xdebug

Tags: php, linux, сервер, docker

Используется докер для проекта. До вчерашнего дня все работало нормально, сегодня при попытке сбилдить проект получаю ошибку

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug"
install failed
ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Конфиг docker-compose.yml

```
   php-fpm:
    container_name: fpm
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
#    links:
#      - mysql
#      - redis
    environment:
      DB_PORT: "3306"
      DB_HOST: "mysql"
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "es:9200"
      REDIS_PORT: "6379"
      REDIS_HOST: "redis"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=aggregator"
    restart: always
```

Конфиг докерфайла

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mariadb-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8 \
    && sed -i -e 's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

#ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
#ENV LANGUAGE ru_RU:en
#ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Такое впечатление, что серверы откуда скачивается xdebug умерли, я не понимаю почему вылетает эта ошибка. Может кто-то сможет помочь мне как установить xdebug каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Судя по всему pecl отвалился, может кто-то знает как установить в докере xdebug без pecl

Comment: [xdebug не совместим](https://coderoad.ru/53095831/Xdebug-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-PHP-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) с php7.3 для выпусков < 2.7
вы можете установить бета-версию xdebug, которая совместима с php7.3:

Comment: Так а как у меня вчера все работало? Типа деприкейтед стало?

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема!

Подумал что трабл с Российской сетью и блокировкой, включил VPN и этой ошибки нет!